# Django Admin: readonly_fields not showing on admin. interface

Tags: django

This should be a pretty straight-forward thing, but it's not working as it should.

**model**

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    lesson_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)
    json_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="", null=True)
    activity_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    learning_language = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    known_language = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**admin**

```
from .models import Lesson

class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['lesson_name']
    readonly_fields = ['json_name', 'activity_type', 'learning_language', 'known_language']

admin.site.register(Lesson, LessonAdmin)
```

But, when I log into the admin site, the fields specified in `readonly_fields` don't show up at all. I've also tried including the field names in a tuple instead of a list (as the documentation specifies), but that gives me an error even.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual fields displayed are only set in `list_display`, `fields` and `fieldsets`. `readonly_fields` just tells the admin, of those that it *would* display, which to display as read-only. So just add the same fields to your `fields` list as well. It's duplication, which is annoying, but more explicit.

```
class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['lesson_name', 'json_name', 'activity_type', 'learning_language', 'known_language']
    readonly_fields = ['json_name', 'activity_type', 'learning_language', 'known_language']
```

And it doesn't matter if you use a tuple or a list, the django admin accepts both.